# Why is .fetch() undefined for Collections?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've my models and views for Backbone.js in separate files. The models and collections go like this

```
$(function(){

    TodoList.Models.Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
        url: function (){
                return this.id? '/todos/' + this.id : '/todos/' ;
                },
        initialize: function () {
                }
    });

    TodoList.Collections.Todos = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: TodoList.Models.Todo,
        url: "/todos"
});

});
```

The view code is:

```
$(function(){
    Todos = TodoList.Collections.Todos;
    TodoList.Views.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#todo_app"),
    events: {
        "submit form#new_todo": "createTodo"
    },
    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, 'addOne', 'addAll');
        Todos.bind("add", this.addOne);
        Todos.bind("refresh", this.addAll);
        Todos.bind("all", this.render);
        Todos.fetch();
    },
        .
        .
        .
});
```

The javascript won't run now. It says the fetch() function is undefined. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a new instance of the Todos collection:

```
Todos = new TodoList.Collections.Todos();
```

Comment: In this tutorial, 
https://github.com/AndrewGertig/backbone-demo/blob/master/public/javascripts/dogs.js

inside the AppView code block, there is no new object created for Dogs collections and fetch is used.

Comment: @ApoorvParijat: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). And saying `var todos = new TodoList.Collections.Todos()` would be more conventional.

Comment: I was in a hurry, so couldn't accept then. Anyway, thanks for reminding and for the tip.